# How to install grunt in elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my app with beanstalk. I start my local environment with `grunt dev`. The error shows that grunt cannot be found.

After logging onto the server with `eb ssh`, I see that `npm` is also not installed.

I'm looking for next steps in trouble shooting this issue.

**.ebextensions/01_grunt.config**

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: "grunt dev"
```

**eb logs**

```
...
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
Wed, 04 Mar 2015 19:07:54 GMT express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead at server.js:6:7
static file request : [object Object]
Wed, 04 Mar 2015 19:07:54 GMT express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead at server.js:12:7
Error: ENOENT, stat '/var/app/current/libs/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.css'
static file request : [object Object]
static file request : [object Object]
Error: ENOENT, stat '/var/app/current/dist/libs.js'
Error: ENOENT, stat '/var/app/current/dist/app.js'
static file request : [object Object]
Error: ENOENT, stat '/var/app/current/favicon.ico'
static file request : [object Object]
Error: ENOENT, stat '/var/app/current/favicon.ico'
Listening on 8081

sh: grunt: command not found
sh: grunt: command not found
sh: grunt: command not found
sh: grunt: command not found
...
```

**Update:**

Tried: **.ebextensions/01_grunt.config** (note the **npm install**)

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: "npm install && grunt dev"
```

**eb logs**

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "&&" "grunt" "dev"
npm ERR! cwd /var/app/current
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock grunt, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR!     at unlock (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:44:11)
npm ERR!     at cb (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:30:5)
npm ERR!     at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:47:20
npm ERR!     at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:30:7
npm ERR!     at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.31-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:167:38
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: EB will run `npm install` for you, but grunt will not be globally installed as you may have it in your dev environment.  The [default start commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-nodejs) are to run `app.js`, `index.js`, and `npm start` in that order.  Can you use `npm start` or a JS file to start?

Comment: @JamesWing I can, but my `gruntfile` creates an `app.js` and a `lib.js` file which both are ignored in my `.gitignore`.  I don't think eb will copy over files that are git ignored. Correct?

Comment: I understand, but I agree with the answer from @firstdoit -- `grunt dev` is probably not a great fit for EB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to make your BeanStalk run `grunt`. This adds an unnecessary point of failure.

You should deliver compiled assets and add a `npm start` script with the correct command to start your app.

For example, in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node myApp.js"
  }
}
```

If you **really** want it, though, you can add `grunt-cli` as a dependency and use the bin in `node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt` to run it. But, please: don't!

Comment: I agree. I will tailor my app to this approach

Comment: Can you explain why it's better to deliver compiled assets instead of run task on EB?